# Getting Undefined after subscribe successfully called in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have successfully called the API and data from it however if I read the variable I am getting **"Undefined"**.

**Service Class which call api to get data**

```
export class DataServiceService {

   constructor(private http: Http) { }

   url: string = "http://localhost:60263/api/values";

   getEmployeesData(): Observable<EmployeeDetails[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.url).map((res: Response) => res.json());
   }
}
```

**Subscribing data**

```
export class AppComponent {

   emp: EmployeeDetails[];

   constructor(private dataServe: DataServiceService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.dataServe.getEmployeesData().subscribe(res => this.emp = res);
   }

   clEmployeesCount: Number = this.emp.length; **Getting undefined here**
   clShowEmployee: boolean = false;
   clCreateEmployee: boolean = false;
}
```

**however this works fine at HTML part**

```
<div *ngIf="emp">
  <ul *ngFor="let user of emp">
   <li>{{user.ID}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is an asynchronous call, you can't know when it will be returned. 
So move the assignment into the `subscribe` function

```
this.dataServe.getEmployeesData().subscribe(res =>  {
   this.emp = res;
   this.clEmployeesCount = emp.length;
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. I wonder why it has been downvoted.

Comment: This solved the issue, However I was wondering if there is any option for Synchronous call for this.

Comment: @jinnybat Sorry, but no. It is considered and must be asynchronously

Comment: Thanks @SurenSrapyan for the information. However I came across a very strange problem with Post request to a Web API method. application/json content-type request is not even reaching to the web api method however if i change content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded this calls the Web API method. I have tried every possible solutions like cors,allow cross origin nothing works in this case.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. It was related to Cors which was not correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

this.emp is assigned the value only after

```
clEmployeesCount: Number = this.emp.length;
```

**Getting undefined here**  is executed.

Either you could move

```
clEmployeesCount: Number = this.emp.length;
```

inside the subscribe or 
assign a null array initially

```
emp: EmployeeDetails[] = []
```

to avoid the error. Moving it into subscribe is the proper method.